# Precise current measurement upto .05uA

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am working on a circuit where i have to measure currents from -500uA to 5mA. For this i am using 100ohm resistor for converting current to voltage and then this voltage is sent to OP07 and output of this is given to HP7840 isollator whose gain is 8. circuit is working correctly for higher currents but i want to measure .05uA. But since output of this circuit is fluctuating when i am taking readings in 5 decimal points, due to this my readings are not coming accurate. I have no idea why their is fluctuations upto 0-100uV  which is not desired. OP07 thermal noise is 0.2uV/`C and HP-7840 have only 0.1% nonlinearity.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here.. First of all you don't have a question. What do you want us to solve? Second, you're mixing a lot of things. You want to measure from -500 µA to 5 mA, does that include zero? In the title you want to measure up to 0.05 µA.

Comment: Yes it includes zero also. Problem is when i am measuring lower currents with this circuit it is not giving correct reading.

Answer (score 4):

The input noise of a [OP7](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/OP07.pdf) is about 11nV/√Hz. The bandwidth (unless your circuit reduces it) is about 1MHz, so the expected input noise is about 10uV. With a gain of 8 the output noise is about 80-90uV.

You need to reduce the bandwidth.  Work out how often you actually need a measurement, and add low-pass filtering with a roll-off at about double the measurement rate.

Depending on your exact requirements, you might find a transimpedance amplifier a better fit than a series resistor & voltage amplifier.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean the [HCPL-7840](http://www.avagotech.com/cs/Satellite?blobcol=urldata&blobheader=application%2Fpdf&blobheadername1=Content-Disposition&blobheadername2=Content-Type&blobheadername3=MDT-Type&blobheadervalue1=attachment%3Bfilename%3DAV02-1289EN-DS-HCPL-7840-09Jul20121.pdf&blobheadervalue2=application%2Fx-download&blobheadervalue3=abinary%253B%2Bcharset%253DUTF-8&blobkey=id&blobnocache=true&blobtable=MungoBlobs&blobwhere=1430856339798&ssbinary=true), the input-referred noise density is 500 nV/√ Hz. You have a gain of 8, so the output noise density is around 4uV/√ Hz.

The typical noise at the output of the isolator is specified on the datasheet as **31.5mV RMS**, which might be a couple hundred mVp-p. That will be by far your dominant intrinsic noise source. If you are using a 0-10V measurement span with 5 digits resolution that's 100uV resolution... yes, you are going to see a lot of noise.

[image]

Suggest you first read the isolator data sheet section on reducing noise.